# How to Arrange Support => Thumbnail

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox

Good Afternoon,

I've created a CPT that mainly uses Featured Images, I would like to know how to rearrange this box to appear in the center where 'content editor' would go instead of the right (Default).

here is what i've so far,

```
$args = array('public' => true, 'label' => 'MisterZik', 
'menu_position' => 10,  'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'));

register_post_type('zik_images', $args);
```

Thanks!

[image: I would like to move the box on the right to the center.]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you can do is replace it, here's what I use:

```
/** Use "Featured Image" Box As A Custom Box **/
function post_type_featured_image() {
    add_meta_box(
        'postimagediv',
        __('Your Custom Title Here'),
        'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 
        'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE', 
        'normal', 
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'post_type_featured_image' );
```

As an explaination you can read up on the [`add_meta_box()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

You can replace the text here: `__('Your Custom Title Here')` with whatever you like, this is going to replace the "Featured Image" title.

You need to replace `'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE'` with your actual post type, should you want to replace it on Built-In Pages, you would replace that text with `page`.

The Context is `'normal'` to tell it to add it on the left instead of the sidebar and finally `'high'` tells WP to add it toward the top. Again, for more indepth info please check out the `add_meta_box()` function.